# Scan Barcode from image ZBar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I scan any barcode by using zbar at that time this API scans a barcode also It scans an image.
any one please help me to do this...assume that I have one Mazza Bottle in that bottle Barcode is there But particular barcode is on Orange plastic. Ween ever I scan any barcode image at that time zbar scans barcode with orange color... So I just want to nget barcode not any other portion than barcode.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
   capture = [ZBarCaptureReader new];
   capture.captureDelegate = self;
   reader.readerDelegate = self;
   reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
   ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;

    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];

}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;

    for(symbol in results)
        // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
        break;
    label.text = symbol.data;
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
    [reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];

}
```

Comment: hi iPatel.... can u please quide me what to do

Comment: What is your problem ? zBar is use for only scan barcode image/picture so you don't worry about orange color.. it's automatically avoid it.

Comment: actually bro I have placed "vicks inhaler" in my hand so when I move my iPhone to scan barcode of that Vicks Inhaler at that time It scans barcode with my finger

Comment: Why don't you just generate a clean barcode using the data that was scanned?

Comment: Mr. Paul Will u please tell me how to generat it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

zbar doesnt retouch the image for you. it gives you the image it scanned without modification.

you can get the cropped image (the one in the rectangle of the scanner view)

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    ZBarImage *cropped = [[ZBarImage alloc] initWithCGImage:img.CGImage crop:((ZBarReaderViewController*)imagePicker).scanCrop size:img.size];
    //...
}
```

Comment: Sir problem is not that   actually bro I have placed "vicks inhaler" in my hand so when I move my iPhone to scan barcode of that Vicks Inhaler at that time It scans barcode with my finger

Comment: I want to ask u that When I scan any barcode which is on any real time product......... That particular product is in my hand  when I scan barcode of that product in my hand  at that time Zbar does not scan barcode  only but It scans barcode as well as my fingers

Comment: One More Thing:::::  When Camera represents at that time Green Rectangle comes to catch any barcode...... SO is it possible to get green portion only for setting into imageview.

Comment: ah so you wanna crop the image! Ill look at it

Comment: YEs I just want to get barcode only... Actually how to crop barcode from an image I dont have any idea

Comment: you can crop to the green rectangle like Ive shown in my answer

Comment: Yes but how to crop that green colored rectangle?

Comment: Actullay Ur code is not working ... when I set that
      UIImage * img1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)(cropped)];
    imageView.image = img1;

Comment: At that time Zbar Camera dismisses and Imageview does not display any image  It means Imageview might set nill image by cropped image